# Bootable DVD 12.04.3 LTS works on some Windows XP PC's, not on others

Tags: 12.04, boot, hardware, system-installation

I downloaded 32bit 12.04LTS to DVD and loaded on three different Windows XP PC's (one as dual boot). All three were very old PC's with less than 512MB memory or less.
For some reason I can't install Ubuntu 12.04.3LTS on any other 32bit Windows XP nor Windows 7 PC's. The Windows 7 PC has 4GB Memory the others less than 1GB.
I've downloaded 12.04 again to both (another) DVD and USB, checked the bio settings and rebooted but nothing seems to work.
The PC's (I've tried three of them) all just open to Windows. 
When I go to "My Computer", I see the Ubuntu disc or file but it won't boot. I can't open the disc to find an .exe file.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you are 'burning' the ISO as bootable?

How to for USB - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

How to DVD/CD - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto